# Sorting of coupons in the right way

Tags: query

I´m using custom post types on my site and i need to sort these coupons in this way:

1. New Coupon ending TODAY ---
2. New Coupon ending 05.03.2015
3. New Coupon ending 06.03.2015
4. New Coupon ending 07.03.2015
5. ---
6. Old Coupon expired 03.03.15
7. Old Coupon expired 02.03.15
8. Old Coupon expired 01.03.15

These coupons have a custom field named unixendet with unix values (tells when a coupon is ending) in it - F.x.: unixendet = 1428271200

Now i´m using this code for querying two lists in one:

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin'); setlocale(LC_TIME, "de_DE", "german");
$time = current_time( 'timestamp' ); // Get current unix timestamp

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'gutschein',
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '10',
    'posts_per_archive_page' => '10',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    => false,
    'post_status' =>  'published',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'unixendet',
    'meta_value' => $time, // Use the current time from above
    'meta_compare' => '>=', // Compare today's datetime with our event datetime
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => ASC,
);

// get results
$first_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$args2 = array(
    'post_type' => 'gutschein',
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '10',
    'posts_per_archive_page' => '10',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    => false,
    'post_status' =>  'published',
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key' => 'unixendet',
    'meta_value' => $time, // Use the current time from above
    'meta_compare' => '<=', // Compare today's datetime with our event datetime
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => DESC,
);

$second_query = new WP_Query( $args2 );

$result = new WP_Query();
$result->posts = array_merge( $first_query->posts, $second_query->posts );
$result->post_count = count( $result->posts );

// The Loop
?>
<?php if( $result->have_posts() ): ?>
  <?php while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); ?>
```

**The big problem is how it outputs the posts:**

I have 48 coupons: 11 valid ones from args1 AND 37 expired ones from args2

- first page: 10 coupons from args1 AND 10 from args2
- second page: 1 coupon from args1 AND 10 from args2
- third page: 0 coupons from args1 AND 10 from args2

---

- Problem 1: On the second page there is 1 valid coupon, so it would
  make no sense to sort like this. I want all valid ones stay above the
  expired ones.
- Problem 2: It seems that 7 coupons are missing from args2 (page
  number 4 doesn´t exist.) So only 30 from 37 expired posts are showing up.

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that this part:

```
    'post_status' =>  'published',
```

should be:

```
    'post_status' =>  'publish',
```

You can then try the following:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => 'gutschein',
    'pagination'             => true,
    'posts_per_page'         => '10',
    'posts_per_archive_page' => '10',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'    => false,
    'post_status'            => 'publish',
    'paged'                  => $paged,
    'meta_key'               => 'unixendet',
);

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'emti_orderby' );
$q = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'emti_orderby' );
```

where we setup a conditional ordering:

```
/**
 * Modify the order by part:
 */

function emti_orderby( $orderby )
{     
    global $wpdb;
    $time = current_time( 'timestamp' ); // Get current unix timestamp

    return "
        CASE
            WHEN {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value >= {$time} 
                THEN  {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value+0 - {$time}+0      
            WHEN {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value < {$time} 
                THEN {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value+0
        END
        ASC
    ";
}
```